# Tratando de usar ngx-tui-image-editor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

Trato de actualizar imagen de componente tui con el [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-tui-image-editor)

```
import { IOptions, ToastUiImageEditorComponent } from 'ngx-tui-image-editor';
```

Yo ya importé el ngx en app.module y el import anterior es el del componente

```
@ViewChild(ToastUiImageEditorComponent, { static: true }) editorComponent: ToastUiImageEditorComponent;
```

Este es el Elemento como tal

Trato de actualizar la imagen de

```
<tui-image-editor [options]="config"></tui-image-editor>
```

Intenté con el options pero nunca cambia, luego intenté con

```
this.editorComponent.options.includeUI.loadImage.path = <string>await this.createImageFromBlob(res);
```

dónde createImageFromBlob genera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De igual forma este es el option

```
public config: IOptions = {
  includeUI: {
    loadImage: {
      path: '',
      name: 'image'
    }
  }
}
```

E intenté cambiarlo pero no pude

Además de esto ¿Cómo leo la imagen una vez cargada?

¿Cómo uso este modulo correctamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de horas de investigación y gracias a la hermosa [documentación](https://nhn.github.io/tui.image-editor/latest/ImageEditor) de ToastUI pude resolverlo

Era más facil de lo que creí, solo pedí la información en ngAfterViewInit, ósease, después de que se cargara el componente, después de esto, hice la petición de la url que deseaba colocar e hice

```
this.editorComponent.editorInstance.loadImageFromURL(image.img, res.data.line + res.data.code);
    this.editorComponent.editorInstance.ui.activeMenuEvent();
```